# Azcopy "--put-md5" parameter confusion

Tags: azure

I have a confusion about the **--put-md5** parameter. When I use azcopy command to upload a file to my Azure Storage account without **--put-md5** parameter, the uploaded blob's **Content-MD5 property** seem to be created defaultly. However, the [AzCopyV10.0.9 Preview Release](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/releases/tag/v10.0.9) illustrates that "as of version 10.0.9, MD5 hashes are NOT created by default". Could you please help to check it? See the screenshots:
[CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Tld5.png)
[Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EU8xN.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested on my side and got same result.MD5 hash is calculated and stored automatically.

This seems to be an azcopy bug.

Here is an opened issue in Microsoft Github azcopy repository.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/1315

**Reply from Microsoft**

For smaller blobs (<256MB IIRC), the service computes it automatically for you.